# How to call sub using for/next VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call some subs using the following code:

```
For i = 1 To 20
    Call staff i
    i = i + 1
Next i
```

and this suppose to call `Sub staff1()`, `Sub staff2()`, `Sub staff3()` and so on, but I am missing something here...

Some one know what should I do ?

Comment: Are the procedures wildly different from each other? If not show a couple and someone may be able to suggest an alternative to 20 distinct routines.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
Run "staff" & i
```

rather than call

of course, it may be possible-and better-to have one routine and pass i as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Application.Run`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim ProcName As String

    For i = 1 To 3
        ProcName = "Staff" & i
        Application.Run ProcName
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Staff1()
    MsgBox "A"
End Sub

Sub Staff2()
    MsgBox "B"
End Sub

Sub Staff3()
    MsgBox "C"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In such situation use the following way of calling your subs:

```
Dim i
For i = 1 To 20
    Application.Run "staff" & i
Next i
```